# How to calculate logarithmized average monthly returns

Tags: calculus

I am currently reading the following paper https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2750064 . On page 57 the researchers state that they calculate the logarithmized average monthly returns as calculated over four non overlapping periods.

The price series looks as follows:

```
price_mth0  price_mth1  price_mth2  price_mth3  price_mth4  price_mth5  price_mth6  price_mth7  price_mth8  price_mth9  price_mth10 price_mth11 price_mth12
     100    99.89974213 90.88634491 105.1879883 100.2683334 92.54978943 93.88592529 79.42245483 75.91511536 74.78253937 86.61391449 82.77873993 83.12158203
```

And the calculated returns are

```
lnreturn_lag1m3m    lnreturn_lag4m6m    lnreturn_lag7m9m    lnreturn_lag10m12m
0.03523995    -0.075832009                 -0.037889559     0.016859641
```

Unfortunately they do not state a formula. I tried several different ways to come to their results but I cannot come up with the right formula. Can anyone helpe me?

For me the correct calculation should be

```
(ln( 82.77873993) - ln(75.91511536)) / 3
```

However, this has 0.02885182 as a result and not 0.03523995

Comment: I'm sorry, I have searched and cannot find the first calculated return anywhere in the paper.

Comment: its in the data appendix